# Detect what element in the same class is clicked and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add_comment", function() {  
 $('.text_area').show();  
});
```

```css
.main_text
{
  width:260px;
  height:75px;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.add_comment
{
  color:#05c;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.text_area
{
   position:relative;
   left:300px;
    top:-120px;
   display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.     Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus       et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
  <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
  <div class="text_area">
    <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.     Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus       et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
  <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
  <div class="text_area">
    <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
  </div>
   <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing         elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque           penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
  <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
  <div class="text_area">
    <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Hello,
I would like click in `Add comment` text and show `class="text_area"`, but now if I click in `Add comment` show all textareas but I would like to detect what was clicked.

> e.g. if I click second `Add comment` second textarea will show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery `next()` method like following.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add_comment", function() {  
 $(this).next('.text_area').show();  
});
```

```css
.main_text
{
  width:260px;
  height:75px;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.add_comment
{
  color:#05c;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.text_area
{
   position:relative;
   left:300px;
    top:-120px;
   display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.     Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus       et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
  <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
  <div class="text_area">
    <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.     Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus       et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
  <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
  <div class="text_area">
    <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
  </div>
   <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing         elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque           penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
  <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
  <div class="text_area">
    <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Is possible use something different than neext () when divs aren't next to each other?

Comment: You can use `nextAll('.text_area').first()` if divs aren't next to each other. Actually it will depend on your html which method you need to use. @V.R

Answer (score 2):

You can try wrapping your elements in a wrapper, and having the click handler particular to the wrapper.

wrapper example:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing         elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque           penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </div>
    <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
    <div class="text_area">
      <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

updated click:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_comment", function() {        
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.text_area').show();      
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gyutjb53/

Answer (score 1):

It is the next sibling so use the [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selector.

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_comment", function() {        
    $(this).next('.text_area').show();      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, wrap elements. Speaking structurally, each of the content blocks are discrete, and should be able to be manipulated discretely. It's the whole "black box" approach -- everything structural to the block is contained by the block.

```js
// When the el with the class add_comment is clicked,
$(".add_comment").on("click", function(){
  // Hide ALL elements with the class text_area,
  $(".text_area").hide();
  // Then just show the one that applies to this click.
  $(this).parent().children(".text_area").show();
})
```

```css
.main_text {
  width: 260px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.add_comment {
  color: #05c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text_area {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -120px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <section class="content-item">
    <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    </div>
    <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
    <div class="text_area">
      <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="content-item">
    <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    </div>
    <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
    <div class="text_area">
      <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="content-item">
    <div class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    </div>
    <p class="add_comment">Add comment</p>
    <div class="text_area">
      <textarea placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```